# Electron child_process.exec('df -h') doesn't work in production on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I built an app with Electron and React which heavily relies on unix commands. I used `child_process.exec` to get necessary data but after I packaged app using `electron-builder` those commands stopped working. I found out that `exec` uses default Windows shell so `cmd` commands work fine. Is there a way to change that behiviour to default in production?
Example:

```
child_process.exec('df -h', (err, stdout, stderr) => {...code here})
```

Comment: But why? Because windows don't have df?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to rewrite half of my code

Comment: Install coreutils for windows http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm